# Conocer tipo de una variable en java

Tags: java

Recién empiezo a trabajar con java y me gustaría saber de qué formas puedo saber el tipo de una variable, si es int, long, short, boolean, etc.

¡Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Hola Manuel, siempre es recomendable realizar lo que hayas investigado o tratado en tus preguntas, te comento que lo que deseas es determinar el tipo de la variable para esto puedes realizarlo de esta forma: ((Object)variable).getClass().getSimpleName()) , agregué una respuesta, saludos!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para conocer el tipo de una variable lo puedes realizar mediante el método `.getClass().getSimpleName()` (también puedes usar `.getName()` ) y realizando un casting de `(Object)` para la variable de la cual deseas conocer su tipo.

> [**getSimpleName()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName--) Devuelve el nombre simple de la clase
>   subyacente como se indica en el código fuente.

Ejemplo:

```
int myInteger = 10;
String myString = "Hola";
double myDouble = 0;
Person myPerson = new Person();
short myShort = 20;

System.out.println("myInteger es de tipo " +  ((Object)myInteger).getClass().getSimpleName());
System.out.println("myString es de tipo " +  ((Object)myString).getClass().getSimpleName());
System.out.println("myDouble es de tipo " +  ((Object)myDouble).getClass().getSimpleName());
System.out.println("myPerson es de tipo " +  ((Object)myPerson).getClass().getSimpleName());
System.out.println("myShort es de tipo " +  ((Object)myShort).getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Salida:

```
myInteger es de tipo Integer
myString es de tipo String
myDouble es de tipo Double
myPerson es de tipo Person
myShort es de tipo Short
```

---

Si ya conoces el tipo de la variable y deseas realizar una **comparación**, puedes usar el operador de comparación de tipos [**instanceof**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

```
    String myString = "Hola";
    double myDouble = 0;
    Person myPerson = new Person();

    if(myString instanceof String){
        System.out.println("Es de tipo String");
    }else{
        System.out.println("No es de tipo String");
    }

    if((Object)myDouble instanceof Double){
        System.out.println("Es de tipo Double");
    }else{
        System.out.println("No es de tipo Double");
    }

    if(myPerson instanceof Person){
        System.out.println("Es de tipo Person");
    }else{
        System.out.println("No es de tipo Person");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar **instanceof** para verificar el objeto al que pertenece.

Por ejemplo

```java
String test = "esto es un string";

if(test instanceof String)
  System.out.println("si es un string");
```

Comment: ¿Pero y si no sé cuál es el tipo? Tendría que hacer un condicional por cada tipo, ¿no? ¿Habría alguna forma de hacerlo más directo? Gracas.

Answer (score -1):

Variable int va desde: -2147486648 hasta 2147486647

Variable long va desde: 9223372036854775808 hasta 9223372036854775807

Variable short va desde: -32768 hasta 32767

Boolean: consiste en 2 valores true o false